# How can I skretch an image with HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css, image

```
<div id="background">
  <img title="Imagen Corporativa" alt="Imagen Corporativa" src= "C:\Users\aleja\Desktop\A. Programacion\Factoria F5\Primer Sprint - Landing Page\Background.jpg"/>
</div>
```

```
#background {
  background-size: cover;
  position: fixed;
  margin-left: 45%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 10% 100%);
  background-image: ("Background.jpg");
  grid-column:2;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

And the image get filled into the `<div>`, and I want it to skretch.
I tried playing with background-size repeat and position, but had no results.

This is what I want to achieve:
[image: Expectation]

And this is what i actually get:
[image: Reality]

I am using the same image.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Thanks Paulie!! I will take note

Comment: Did you try `background-size: contain`?

Answer (score 0):

You can set max-height in specific pixels and set max-width as 100% of the img tag.

```
max-height: 90px;
max-width: 100%;
```

Answer (score 0):

Heey bro! Try to **NOT** wrap your `<img>` tag between `<div>` tags. If you set a class/id in the  tag, then you can call this class or id in the CSS file and modify it at your wish (set the clip-path and all this stuff) like that:

```
.background-image {
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 15% 100%);
    grid-column: 2/2;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 100%
}
```

That way, the image will not behave as a div banckground but as an image itself.

Good luck!

Comment: If it was not clear enough, the solution I propose is to delete de <div> tags wrapping the <img>, and then set a class="background-image" (or any other class name) inside the <img> tag. Then you can modify the CSS as I suggested in the block of  code above